# Registering SIGINT/SIGQUIT signals in a Django application served in Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, signals

I've got a Django application with a queue system (that builds some releases from various developers) that needs to be completed. However, towards the end of the day, I need to shut it down but the running builds should not be terminated. To achieve this, I thought I can catch termination signals (like SIGINT/SIGQUIT/SIGTERM) so that the application can wait for the releases to complete and shut the system down then.

I have the following signal registering system:

```
import time, sys, signal

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    print('Waiting for the releases to complete')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('TERMINATING GRACEFULLY...')
    sys.exit(0)

for sig in [signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGQUIT]:
    signal.signal(sig, signal_handler)
```

When I run the django's development server from the command line with this code snippet, it registers the signal and trigger the handler function. The problem is that my application runs on Docker with nginx and uWSGI in place. When I run the container, it registers the signal but when I stop the docker container, the SIGINT/SIGQUIT signal is caught by the uWSGI, not by python and my signal handler is not triggered.

I'm relatively new to Docker and uWSGI, I couldn't figure out a way to send this signal directly to python. What should I do for the python to catch the signal, not uWSGI?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Here's my entrypoint script.

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start uWSGI using the configuration file
exec uwsgi --ini ./docker/django/uwsgi.ini
```

uwsgi.ini

```
...
module = app.wsgi
socket = path/to/unix/socket.sock
chmod-socket = 666
...
```

Comment: Can you show your entrypoint/cmd inside your Dockerfile for this?

Comment: Looks like the initial suspicion about /bin/sh on pid 1 doesn't apply here. I've removed that answer to hopefully get more attention to your question.